# Multi word url links bug in WYGWAM field

Tags: wygwam, assets

If I create a hyperlink from multiple words in a WYGWAM field it looks fine if I view the source code but when parsed in the browser it adds stuff to the link address causing it to fail.
Example, I type some link text "Results and splits" I then highlight it and click the link button and browse and select the file. This is the source code generated in the WYGWAM field when viewed in the control panel:

```
<a href="/results-archive/2012-13/index.html">Results and splits</a>
```

But this is what the resulting browser source is:

```
/results-archive/2012-13/index.html2012-13/index.html}
```

But if I edit the link text by viewing source in the WYGWAM field and delete the words and then retype the words in source view and then save the link it works perfectly.

Edit:This is only when linking to a file via Assets

EE 2.6.1 WYGWAM 2.7.1

Answer (score 1):

We've got a fix for this locally that will be included in the next release.  Sending the patched files in your support request.